# How to keep the window open: ShellExecuteW(0,0,"powershell.exe", "..","..",SW_SHOW)?

Tags: powershell, shellexecute

from another program (metatrader) I start a ps-script to download some emails:

```
 shl = ShellExecuteW(0,0,"powershell.exe", "-file x.ps1","..\\path\\to\\scripts",SW_SHOW);
```

After a couple of weeks without any problem(!) I saw all of a sudden some red error code in the console - but it was closed too fast the return code (shl) signals no error: shl <=32.

Now I tried to start ShellExecuteW(..) with

```
  shl = ShellExecuteW(0,0,"powershell.exe","..","..",SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);
  # SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE = 4 
  # 4: Displays a window in its most recent size and position. The active window remains active.
```

But again the console disappears :(

1) What do I have to enter so that the console stays open - for me to close 1t manually?
2) How do I force ShellExecuteW(..) to add the error-messages to an error file?

Thanks and a nice weekend,
Gooly

PS: After I re-started the program with ShellExecuteW(..) it runs again without any error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is not ShellExecute, but how Powershell is invoked.

Try this:

```
shl = ShellExecuteW(0,0,"powershell.exe", "-noexit -file x.ps1","..\\path\\to\\scripts",SW_SHOW);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, You could have kept it open by adding `read-host` at the end of your Script.

You can Log error messages by using transcripts (`start-transcript` / `stop-transcript`) or just add error handling to your Script (try catch then log manually).

Regards

Comment: That a way too, but at the moment I don't know where the problem exists so where to place a catch.

Comment: you should allways enclose statements that could throw terminating errors in a try-catch.
For now just add a "start-transcript" at the start of your script and "stop-transcript" at the end, then check the log after you have called it from your app to identify the statements that throw errors.

Comment: Paul, the script was running without any errors for some weeks. And I have started it now again with no changes and no errors. I just have to run it again for some weeks hoping the error occurs again. I think meanwhile the log-file will get too big I guess..

Comment: i see how this could be a problem :) 
you could put the call to the main method of your script in a try catch, without seeing the script its hard to tell you where to put your error handling